# MSXML XPATH & String with Single Quote & Double Quote

Tags: visual-c++, xpath, msxml

I am using Escaping Strings in XPath.

My String in XML File is :

`"Test ' both " quotes"::LGC"`

So I converted it into XPath strings :

`Value[@Name=\"concat(\"Test ' both \",'\" quotes\"::LGC')\"]`

But still MSXML Select Single Node return me E-FAIL.

Any idea what I am missing XPath strings ?

Comment: Why `@Name=\"concat(...)\"`? The `concat` function returns a string value you can compare to the `@Name` attribute with e.g. `@Name=concat()`, putting the `concat` call in XPath string delimiters make is part of a string literal which is not executed so currently your comparison is of `@Name` against a string starting with the word `concat`.

Comment: And please clarify whether the string in the XML starts with and ends with double quotes or whether these are attribute value delimiters in the XML.